# Problema al guardar valores decimales (cifras monetarias ) en una base de datos mysql

Tags: php, mysql

En el momento estoy guardando varios valores que representan cifras monetarias, estos valores los extraigo de un archivo ***csv*** y insertados en una base de datos [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql). Algunos de estos valores se encuentran de la siguiente manera:

```
// pueden llegar con el punto de mil
// siete mil treinta y cuatro 
7.034 
// o sin punto de mil pero con valores decimales
// cuatro mil treinta y cuatro con treinta y cuatro décimas
4034.34
```

El problema ocurre cuando cuando realizo la suma de estos, dejando el punto en cualquiera de los casos el sistema tiende a redondear las cifras lo cual hace que el total sea muy impreciso, tratando de resolver esto antes de hacer la inserción elimino los puntos.

El campo en el que guardo los datos es '**DECIMAL(10,2)**' aunque lo he intentado con NUMERIC o FLOAT pero se sigue presentando lo mismo.

```
//
7034 
// 
403434
```

En el caso del primer valor, al sumarlo da un resultado mas exacto al no tener decimales, lo que no ocurre con el segundo valor que si posee decimales, pues interpreta los últimos dos dígitos como si fuese parte de este es decir " cuatrocientos tres mil, cuatrocientos treinta y cuatro.

espero hacerme entender

Comment: usas el mismo punto para decimales y unidades de mil?

Comment: Creo que el problema se entiende, pero no veo ninguna alternativa para esto, ya que no tienes cómo distinguir si el valor viene con separador de miles o decimales. Por qué ambos usan un punto y no lo típico que uno sea un punto y el otro una coma?

Comment: si los dos usan el punto para decimales y unidades de mil, estos archivos son generados por sistemas diferentes y me son entregados de esa forma, no hay manera de unificarlos o algo similar.

Comment: entonces lamentablemente no hay forma de que puedas almacenar correctamente estos datos

Comment: he pensado antes de registrar el valor diferenciar de alguna manera estos valores y organizarlos antes de hacer la inserción, pero no se me ocurre nada

Comment: ¿Todos los valores están en el mismo archivo? es decir, todos los distintos sistemas ¿escriben sobre el mismo archivo? ¿no hay forma de saber que sistema escribe en que archivo? ¿se puede asumir que nunca habrá mas de 2 decimales?

Comment: @AlanPatiño si guardas en varchar y cuando recuperes el dato lo conviertes al tipo que quiereas?

Comment: Me explico, los valores que tienen el punto de mil y los que tienen decimales vienen en archivos diferentes y se guardan en tablas diferentes en la base de datos, es decir, ejemplo: los de mil son de __Buga__, los de decimales __Bogota__ . no estoy seguro, hasta el momento solo existen hasta dos decimales

Comment: Puedes procesar los archivos o los importas directo a la base de datos?

Comment: Los proceso, capturo solo las columnas que me son util y inserto estos en la base de datos, puedo manipular el valor que como tal quitando los puntos o recorriendo este

Comment: @AlanPatiño pero porque no los guardas como cadenas y asunto solucionado, y cuando quieras hacer alguna operación los conviertes en numeros

Comment: @AlanPatiño, ya que los procesas, ¿por que no los guardas en formato `float`? es decir, si son _Buga_, les quitas el punto, si es _Bogota_, los dejas como están.

Comment: @MarcosGallardo no es lo mejor, por que en caso que quiera agregar otra ciudad municipio o vereda tendría que crear una condición para cada una dependiendo del formato en el que ingrese y la idea es que este lo reconozca. aunque a la final creo que esa sera la salida :(

Comment: @rn3w muchas veces la cantidad de datos es muy extenso entonces yo realizo la suma directamente en una consulta [tag:mysql], de otra manera tendría que hacerlo mediante un ciclo o algo así (creo yo) y esto hace que el tiempo de respuesta sea mucho mas lenta dependiendo de la cantidad de datos, no se si estoy equivocado.

Comment: @AlanPatiño, si el día de mañana agregas otra ciudad ¿y el formato usa comas (`,`)?. Puedes crear [`RegExp`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.preg-match.php) para detectar los distintos formatos, ¿te interesaría hacer esto?

Comment: @AlanPatiño el tiempo de ejecucion de `for` es 1 es decir no es nada, no hablo de un for anidado ni nada parecido

Comment: @MarcosGallardo claro si puedes explicarme como hacerlo quedaría muy agradecido

Comment: @AlanPatiño, el único problema que veo es que, para evitar un errores, es necesario definir un máximo de 2 decimales. Por ejemplo, el número `1,000`, no se puede saber si es `mil` o `uno`.

Answer (score 2):

Ya que usas php porqué no tratar los datos? En los datos que te vengan de un CSV dónde el punto `.` sea utilizado para unidades de mil usa la función [**str_replace()**](http://php.net/manual/es/function.str-replace.php), de manera que tengas una coherencia en todos los datos y los puedas tratar sistemáticamente, ya que sino será imposible, porque **mysql** nunca sabrá si ese punto es unidad de mil o decimal.

Primero con la función **[decimal(n,0)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms187746.aspx)** en sql devuelves los números sin decimales, entonces sabrás que ese punto es para las unidades de mil.

```
// pueden llegar con el punto de mil
// siete mil treinta y cuatro 
7.034 
$csv1 = str_replace('.','','7.034');
(float) $csv1;
// o sin punto de mil pero con valores decimales
// cuatro mil treinta y cuatro con treinta y cuatro décimas
4034.34
```

Comment: Sabes como me podria dar cuenta cuando el punto es una unidad de mil o un decimal ?

Answer (score 1):

Se me ocurren opciones para respetar el decimal si necesitas que sean exactas las operaciones o sino, redondear.

**Respetar los decimales:**

Usar [settype](http://php.net/manual/es/function.settype.php) para que el valor se convierta al tipo de dato que desees, especialmente útil en tu caso si los valores que obtienes en realidad son strings.

```
// Antes de sumar
settype($cifra_monetaria, 'double');
var_dump($cifra_monetaria); // Te dirá el tipo de variable
```

**Redondear decimales**

Usa [round](http://php.net/manual/es/function.round.php):

```
echo round(3.6, 0);      // 4
echo round(1.95583, 2);  // 1.96
```

Answer (score 1):

Estás atacando al problema desde el lado equivocado. Deberías establecer un formato único entre tus datos. No deberías almacenarlos **jamás como varchar**, siempre con un formato numérico. Si no se puede establecer un protocolo para recibir los datos bien formateados, se implementa un conversor, y se establece en el protocolo que, si viene de esos orígenes, se debe pasar por el conversor antes de insertarlos.

No obstante, si los decimales nunca son 3, podemos pensar una solución un tanto "sucia":
eliminar todos los puntos que estén después de 1 dígito y seguidos por 3 dígitos (ni más ni menos).

```php
function eliminar_puntos_tres_digitos($valor){
    return preg_replace('/(\d)\.(?=\d{3}(?!\d))/', '$1', $valor);
}
```

*Cabe destacar que este método fallaría con cualquier número que tenga 3 cifras decimales.*

Resultado:

```
Original: 123.00        Resultado: 123.00
Original: 123.0001      Resultado: 123.0001
Original: 123.456       Resultado: 123456
Original: 123.456.789   Resultado: 123456789
Original: 123.          Resultado: 123.
Original: .123          Resultado: .123
Original: 123.456.7     Resultado: 123456.7
Original: 123.456.789.1 Resultado: 123456789.1
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/f3lsrb